# Flutter - How to query search item in List

Tags: list, dart, flutter

I want search request on the `List<Food>` that I got. I have used a query method like this:

`_foodList.where((food) => food.name == userInputValue).toList();`

however, the search asked me to search with complete text and the right capitalization of the text.

how if I want to process a compilation of `"dish"`, then all the names of foods that have the word `"dish"` will display in `List`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Lower-case or upper-case all strings before comparison and use `contains()` instead of `==`:

```
_foodList.where((food) => food.name.toLowerCase().contains(userInputValue.toLowerCase()).toList();
```

If values can be `null` you need to add additional checks.

Comment: Hi bro, do you know this case?
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617360/flutter-how-do-distance-filters-then-display-lists-based-on-the-nearest-positi)

Comment: @GunterZochbauer is it possible to search list of list? Ex: `list<String> posts = [...,...]`.. ```Var result = _foodList.where((food) => food.name.toLowerCase().contains(userInputValue.toLowerCase()) || posts. //And also this array```

Comment: It's probably better to create a new question.

Comment: @BloodLoss any success?

Comment: @Rohit yes I found way to do it

Comment: @BloodLoss please help me with the same!